# How can I make keys optional in Overpass API queries / osm-scripts?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I found

```
<osm-script output="json" timeout="25">
  <!-- gather results -->
  <union>
    <!-- query part for: “waterway=*” -->
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="amenity" v="parking"/>
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
  </union>
  <!-- print results -->
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

to give many parking spots (but not considering streets where you can park at the border - might be a lack of available information).

It does, however, also give private parking spots.

When I add

```
<has-kv k="access" v="public"/>
```

it removes the private ones, but also a couple of public ones that seem not to have the attribute. Is there a way to (a) "subtract" elements (e.g. `<has-kv k="access" v="private"/>`) or (b) make the presence of a key (e.g. `access`) optional but enforce a value (e.g. `public`) if it is public?

Comment: Just a side note: `access=public` is *not* a correct tag in OSM! The correct tag is `access=yes` but you won't find this very often because it is usually the default.

Comment: Another side note: you should really consider switching to Overpass QL format. Overpass XML is really dated these days, and all current documentation and examples are focused on Overpass QL only! That's easily possible in overpass turbo --> Export --> Query --> convert to Overpass QL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [negation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Negation) operator:

```
<has-kv k="access" modv="not" v="private"/>
```

Your whole query with the negation from above:

```
<osm-script output="json" timeout="25">
  <!-- gather results -->
  <union>
    <!-- query part for: “waterway=*” -->
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="amenity" v="parking"/>
      <has-kv k="access" modv="not" v="private"/>
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
  </union>
  <!-- print results -->
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

Or in more readable OverpassQL:

```
[timeout:25]
[out:json]
;
(
  way
    ["amenity"="parking"]
    ["access"!="private"]
    {{bbox}};
);
out;
>;
out skel qt;
```